# Write new line to file with variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a new line to a file after writing a variable. How do I do that?
Here's what I have but isn't working:

```py
abc = "Test"
myfile.write(abc\n)
```

Comment: It's a string `abc="Test\n" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
abc = "Test"
myfile.write(f"{abc}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to concatenate both strings, the one stored in the variable `abc` and `"\n"`

```
myfile.write(abc + "\n")
```

Comment: You can't concatenate two strings together when writing a file.

Comment: @RyanPublications Can you explicit that ? Because 2 strings concatenated is just one string, then it's written in the file ;)

Comment: @RyanPublications not possible, that does 100% same as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider where the cursor is in your file_handle.

file_handle.write() will write from the beginning of the file if you've open(file, 'w') whereas file_handle.write() will add to the end (And is probably what you want) if you open(file, 'a'). Other than that, the \n in the other answers are also what you want.